# Что обозначает параметр @ в URL страницы?

Tags: url, at

Есть ULR страницы, в котором в конце указан параметр с @. Убирая этот параметр, на странице ничего не меняется, только пропадает заголовок новости. Вопрос в том, за что отвечает этот параметр? И почему в некоторых URL, на одном и том же ресурсе, он есть, а на другом уже нет.[image]

Comment: У разработчиков сайта лучше спросить. Это не какой-то стандартизированный параметр.

Comment: это просто символ. такой же как и буква a, b или цифра 2.

Answer (score 0):

URL символы задокументированы в стандарте [RFC 1738](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738), согласно которому, URL имеет следующую структуру:

<схема>://<логин>:<пароль>@<хост>:<порт>/?<параметры>#<якорь>

где @ – специальный разделитель

[Источник](https://safe-surf.ru/users-of/article/529629/#:%7E:text=%C2%AB%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%C2%BB%20(%40)%20%E2%80%93%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C,%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9.)

Из стандарта [RFC 1738](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738)(страница 3):

> Символы «;», «/», «?», «:», «@», «=" и «&» — это символы, которые
> могут быть зарезервированы для специального значения в схеме.

Т.е. это может быть особенность конкретного сайта, разрабы которого решили использовать этот разделитель, а не тот.